# Restrict new form creation on frontend in Django

Tags: html, jquery, django, django-forms, formset

How can I restrict new form creation using Django formset? For eg. I want to present an "Add row" button to the user which will duplicate a set of input fields, AND, when the number of rows reaches 10, I want to give a prompt to the user that no more rows can be created.

For eg., in the image below, if the user clicks on "+" one more time, it should either do nothing or prompt the user that max number of rows reached or something like that.

[image]

Here is the code to clone more rows (I don't know yet how to restrict rows so no code for that):

```
function cloneMore(selector, prefix) {
    var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
    var total = $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    newElement.find(':input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
        var id = 'id_' + name;
        $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
    });
    newElement.find('label').each(function() {
        var forValue = $(this).attr('for');
        if (forValue) {
          forValue = forValue.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
          $(this).attr({'for': forValue});
        }
    });
    total++;
    $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
    $(selector).after(newElement);
    var conditionRow = $('.form-row:not(:last)');
    conditionRow.find('.btn.add-form-row')
    .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
    .removeClass('add-form-row').addClass('remove-form-row')
    .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @ggorlen just updated the code to clone more rows. I don't have a code attempt to restrict the rows since that's where I need some direction.